# Build MIME message from raw email text

Tags: c#, mimekit

I need to process raw email messages and pull out the To and From addresses. I could just search for 'To: ' but I'd rather do this in a structured way to avoid issues.

How can I build a MIME message from raw email text, then get the To/From headers?

I've seen MimeKit used for sending emails before but don't seem to be able to find a way to hydrate MimeKit message object from a raw string so I can pull out the To/From headers. I get this runtime error if I just try passing raw email text into the constructor:

```
Exception: System.ArgumentException: Unknown initialization parameter: System.String
   at MimeKit.MimeMessage..ctor(Object[] args)
   at AWSS3Test.Services.CallS3.ListingObjectsAsync()
```

Google has returned nothing of use.

It doesn't have to be MIMEKit, but how can I do this?

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit#parsing-messages You'll have to either wrap your message with a stream or read it directly from disk

Comment: Your link didn't work but you set me on the right track thanks. I'll answer my own question, needs to be a stream and use Load method not constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to use .Load not the constructor and string needs to be converted to a stream

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(TestEmail);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
message = MimeMessage.Load(stream);
```